# What is the correct pattern for using MessageData with Sagas

Tags: masstransit

When using the [Claim Check](https://masstransit.io/documentation/patterns/claim-check) pattern either within a [Saga](https://masstransit.io/documentation/patterns/saga), or when the message data needs passing to an additional message, what is the correct approach to use?

The two options I can see are:

1. Deserialise the message data into the saga state, have it stored in full in the saga state, then use the relevant `Put` method to create a new copy of the data in the message data repository.

```cs
// At the source of the message
Content = await _messageDataRepository.PutString(content),

// In the Saga receiving the message
context.Saga.Content = await context.Message.Content.Value;

// Later in the Saga when passing the value on, call PutString again
Content = await _messageDataRepository.PutString(content),
```

This option feels the safest, but results in a lot of duplication of data both inside the Saga and in the Message Data Repository.

2. Store the Address of the already existing data in the repository and then pass this on to other messages:

```cs
// At the source of the message
Content = await _messageDataRepository.PutString(content),

// In the Saga receiving the message
context.Saga.ContentAddress = context.Message.Content.Address;

// Later in the Saga when passing the value on, call PutString again
Content = new GetMessageData<T>(address, _messageDataRepository, new StringMessageDataConverter(), cancellationToken);
```

In this example I've just saved the Uri to the Saga as I'm using MongoDB for the Saga storage and it does not know how to save a `MessageData<T>` in Bson, so throws an example if I try to store the whole object.

This reduces the amount of duplicate data, but feels like it may be abusing the way this feature was designed to be used, so doesn't seem quite right to me.

In addition to the Saga problem, this question would also be applicable inside a consumer receiving a message, then passing the data on:

```cs
public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<MyMessage> context)
{
    var content = await context.Message.Content.Value;

    // Handle message then raise an event that includes the content, should I use

    await context.Publish<MyOtherMessage>(new
    {
        Content = context.Message.Content;
    });

    // or 

    await context.Publish<MyOtherMessage>(new
    {
        Content = await _messageDataRepository.PutString(content);
    });
}
```

Is there a best practice approach for handling these situations?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, it's better to manage documents/large data on your own, such as writing it to S3 (or whatever blob storage engine) and simply pass the URI to load it through the chain of components. And then inject your own service to load that data in your consumers/saga activities when it is actually needed.

> Frankly, message data needs a refresh but it isn't anywhere near the top of my list of things to work on at this point.